# Django Mixed Block

Tags: python, reactjs, django, nginx

I have a problem on my website I get a mixed block, the server is written in django and the front is in react + connected ssl certificate + nginx, how can I fix this problemconfig nginx,

I have no idea how to go to the Django https server and how to connect a certificate there, whether a certificate is needed separately for the server side and what can be done in general

```
server {
  listen 3000;
  listen [::]:3000 ipv6only=on;
  server_name localhost;
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate     crt.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key key.key;
  ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;


  access_log  /var/log/nginx/httpstatus.access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/httpstatus.error.log;




  location / {
      root /data/www;
      index index.html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /;
   }
}
```

I will be very pleased if you tell me where else this problem could arise